# my shell name has been changed

Tags: macos, shell, docker

my username in shell prompt changed to `ark-newsdrive3`:

```
(base) ark-newsdrive3: ~ maxx $
```

I was experimenting with docker, can it be the cause of this?

Comment: Is that your username, or the computer's hostname? If it's the hostname, it's probably just a confused DNS server trying to be "helpful" -- see my answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

try

```bsh
exit
```

and/or

```bsh
deactivate
```

It looks as though you are in a conda or python virtual environment shell inside a docker container.

If you aren't in a container the deactivate command should at least get you out of the virtual environment.

```bsh
whoami
```

Should tell you who the shell is running under and

```bsh
pwd #print working directory
```

should tell you where you are

Once out

```bsh
sudo docker ps
```

will give you a list of running containers and you can stop a container with

```bsh
docker stop my_container
```

where my_container is the name or id of said container.